# Create Session Based On Visitors IP addresses In Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In My Codeigniter Website There Is A Voting Option, I Want's To Allow Every User To Vote Only Once In Every 24 Hours.
Visitors Are Not Registered Users.
So, I Want To Do That Using Visitors Device MAC address (Which Should Be Unique).
I try This But It Gives Same MAC For All Visitors.

My Objective Is To Create Unique Session For Every Visitor For Next 24 HOUR Based On Their Device's MAC Address.
How Can I Do This..
Or There Is Any Better Way.

Comment: On localhost `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` It will gives you the same. Did you try on production ?

Comment: yes, my website is at online server.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CI's function: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::ip_address

```
$ip = $this->input->ip_address();
echo $ip;
```